# Is there a word for words that are closely related but not synonyms?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word which means the situation where there are two ideas that seem the same at first glance, but when they are closely looked at, they are seen to mean different things.

Examples I'm thinking of are ideas like "Intelligent & Wise" or "Weather & Climate".

Comment: The words/ titles are 'near synonyms', hypernym 'confusables'. But the closely-related  ideas/concepts themselves...?

Comment: Or *hyponyms*? Wise and intelligent are *synonyms*, aren't they?

Comment: @Decapitated Soul 'Synonyms' were defined as 'words interchangeable in some sentences etc with no or negligible shift in meaning' (the word is near-pointless if one insists on 'always interchangeable ...). 'Wise' and 'intelligent' are thus synonyms, but I'd say that the overlap is far from perfect. Some doctors still smoke. And see [this Guardian Article, 'So you think you're smart, stupid?'](https://www.theguardian.com/education/2002/jun/25/highereducation.academicexperts).  And though I believe all can develop in intelligence, wise people more so, the following appears at ...

Comment: [developgoodhabits.com](https://www.developgoodhabits.com/successful-people-failed/): ' ... As a child, he was thought to be dumb and told that he would never be a success by many of his teachers because his mind would often wander in class.' // [later] 'When asked about the many thousands of failures he had when trying to create the light-bulb he famously said, “I have not failed. I’ve just found 10,000 ways that won’t work” '. Edison was wise enough to try again after a failed attempt. An intelligent (?) man might have decided to try to improve the oil lamp.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, Thank you for explanation. :)

Comment: What's a synonym??

Comment: @Hot Licks a usually-non-identical twin.